# Eclipse Theme Ids

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse4 RCP Application. When I moved to running the application as a stand-alone deployment the theme default to some old-school grey-scaled theme. Does anyone know the actual theme id for Windows 7 (Juno) theme?

Answer (score 0):

try `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4.classic_win7`

//EDIT
You can do a trick like this by setting your theme to Windows 7 Style:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager().getCurrentTheme().getId();
```

Comment: PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager().getTheme("org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4.classic_win7") is null. Do I need to add a dependency to something to get the theme?

Comment: So just set your theme to Windows 7 style and use `getCurrentTheme().getId()`